# Java Tree Struct & Breadth-first-search

Tags: java

I created a simple parameterized tree structure, based on a root Node. Each node holds a arraylist of its childnotes and a link to its parent. Thats simple.

Now a problem that I'm not able to solve (in near future):

I want to write a breadth-first search over this tree. I want to implement this feature with the help of a (implemented) iterator interface. But I'm really unable to bring this to work:
Problem is the also iterable List-structure. I don't know how to implement the hasNext(), next() and remove() functions :/

Do you have any idea?

Greetings

**Code:**

```
public class Tree<T> implements Iterator<T>{

private Node<T> root;

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public Tree() {
    super();        
}

/**
 * Return the root Node of the tree.
 * @return the root element.
 */    
public Node<T> getRoot() {
    return this.root;
}

/**
 * Set the root Element for the tree.
 * @param Root the root element to set.
 */
public void setRoot(Node<T> Root) {
    this.root = Root;
}
...
```

**and**

public class Node {

```
public List<Node<T>> children;
public Node<T> parent;
public T data;

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public Node() {
    super();
}

/**
 * Create a Node<T> with an instance of T.
 * @param data an instance of T.
 */
public Node(T nodeData) {
    this();
    setData(nodeData);        
}

/**
 * Create a Node<T> with an instance of T.
 * @param data an instance of T.
 */
public Node(T nodeData, Node<T> parentNode) {
    this();       

    setData(nodeData);
    setParent(parentNode); 

}
...
```

Comment: The tree should not implement `Iterator<T>`, it should implement `Iterable<T>`. The iterator then should be a separate class, an instance of which is returned by the `Iterable.iterator()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `iterator()` method will create an `Iterator<Node<T>>`, which will be initialized with a `Queue<Node<T>>` containing only the root.

`Iterator.next()` will take the first element from the stack, insert to the stack all its children and return it. [Don't forget to pop it as well]

`Iterator.remove()` will remove the last element from its parent's list of `children` [you can access the parent using your `parent` field.

Also note, syntactically, you should implement [`Iterable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and not `Iterator<T>`. The iterator you'll create [as described above] will implement [`Iterator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Comment: After the removal of a Node the Iterator might want to remove its children from the Queue though. But you cannot remove elements from the end of a Queue. You would either have to change Queue to Deque or use a second Queue to remember which Nodes you have to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Node` class needs to implement the `Iterable` interface and not the `Iterator' interface.

The `Iterable` interface essentially says 'this class can return an iterator and be iterated over', whereas the `Iterator` interface says 'I can iterate over something and return those items'. The `Iterable` interface requires an implementation of `Iterator` in order to work.

Here's a quick, contrived, example (not tested, but you should get the gist).

```
public class MyList implements Iterable<Integer> {

    public List<Integer> x;

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new MyListIterator(this);
    }

}
```

Here would be a simple iterator for that class:

```
public class MyListIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

    private List<Integer> list;
    private int index;

    public MyListIterator(MyList list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.index = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.index < this.list.x.size()
    }

    public Integer next() {
       Integer i = this.list.x.get(this.index);
       this.index += 1;
       return i;
    }

    public void remove() {
      //Not implemented
    }

}
```

It may help you to see how you would use an iterator explicitly:

```
MyList list = new MyList();
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the fast feedbacks and explanations! In my implementation wouldn't it be better to implement iterable over nodes instead of the tree? I am a little confused ...

Comment: Yes, certainly. This example was meant to show how these interfaces work together, and not how you should implement them yourself. @amit describes the algorithm you need in your `Iterator`.